# Transparent lines exist in histograms

Tags: gnuplot

How can I remove the transparent lines exited in histograms?
    [image: map1]
    [image: map2]
    set terminal postscript portrait color enhanced lw 1 10
    set output "mtest.ps"
    cd "./out_combine"
    set multiplot
    set size 1.0, 0.14
    set lmargin 0
    set rmargin 1
    set tmargin 1
    set bmargin 1

```
set style data lines
set style fill solid 1.00 noborder
set boxwidth 0.75 absolute
set style histogram rowstacked
set style data histograms

unset ylabel
unset xlabel
unset xtics
set origin 0.050, 0.000
unset ylabel
set ytics nomirror font ",11"
set style increment default
set xtics nomirror norangelimit
set ytics 0,30,150
set size 0.9,0.9
set size ratio 0.4
set xtics("05/01" 0,"05/11"150,"05/17" 300,"05/23" 450,"05/29" 600,"06/04" 750,"06/10" 900,"06/16" 1050,"06/22" 1200,"06/28" 1330 ) font ", 10"
plot [][0:150]'test1.txt' using (\$2) lc rgb "#EF476F" ,\
          'test2' using (\$2) lc rgb "#8ac926",\
          'test3.txt' using (\$2) lc rgb "#1982c4" ,\
          'test4.txt' using (\$2)  ,\
          'test5.txt' using (\$2) lc rgb "#c77dff"
```

Comment: My suspicion would be maybe something with (sub)pixel rendering? What happens if you do `set boxwidth 1.0 relative`? But this is just a "remote guess", since I don't have the exact data to reproduce this.

Comment: @theozh Your advice was really helpful! Thank you very much! I do `set boxwidth 2.0 relative` to solve the problem.

Comment: @theozh But I couldn't fully understand `set boxwidth relative with absoulate`, I do `set boxwidth 2.0 absoulate`, it could work either.